# Error connecting to Mlab

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am running this node app, when I run it locally with my mongodb, it runs fine, but when trying to connect to Mlab, but I keep getting some kinda weird error that I can't really figure out where the error is

**Error message:**

```
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Error connecting to mongodb!
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

**index.js**

```
const   con            = require('./con');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

  mongoose.Promise = con.mongoose.Promise;

  mongoose.connect(con.mongoose.connection)
      .then(() => {
          console.log('Connected to mongodb!');
          require('./app.js');
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.log('Error connecting to mongodb!');;                                                       
      });
```

**con.js**:

```
module.exports = {
    port: process.env.NODE_PORT || 8080,
    mongoose: {
        Promise: require('bluebird'), //mongoose promise library
        //connection: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mmmmm',
    mongoose.createConnection(''mongodb://[username:password@]host1');
    }
};
```

Here is my **app.js**:

```
const   express           = require("express"),
        compress          = require("compression"),
        bodyParser        = require("body-parser"),
        cookieParser      = require("cookie-parser"),
        mongoose          = require("mongoose");
        session           = require("express-session"),
        bcrypt            = require("bcrypt"),
        logger            = require("morgan"),
        config            = require('./con');

    const app = express();
    app.enabled('trust proxy');

    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(compress());

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(express.static("public"));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(cookieParser());      

    app.use(function(req, res, next){
        if (req.session && req.session.userId)
        req.isLoggedIn = true;
        else
        req.isLoggedIn = false;
        next();
        });

        app.use('/', require('./routes/router'));

app.listen(config.port, () => {
    utils.info('Express server listening on port ' + con.port);
    utils.info('http://localhost:' + con.port);
});
```

I also tried:

```
module.exports = {
    port: process.env.NODE_PORT || 8080,
    mongoose: {
        Promise: require('bluebird'), //mongoose promise library
    },
   url : 'mongodb://[username:password@]host1'
};
```

Please someone help me out, I have crawled SO, but go no solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you using mongoose 5.x , remove the

```
{ useMongoClient : true }
```

because that option is no longer necessary in mongoose 5.x

Comment: leaving `{ useMongoClient : true }` will only leave you with a warning, but your app will still run. And removing it will only clear the warning, but won't solve the problem.